Collapsible rows on table show incorrect data if more than one row is selected using ReactJs
I am using react-collapsible to show a list of websites. When a user clicks on a row it expands and shows all associated sites.
The problem is that if the user clicks on a row, then another row it will show the data from the second clicked website in the first one.
I understand what is happening - (it's down to the associated sites being stored in state on each click therefore populating the incorrect expanded row with the latest associated sites), but I'm not sure how to go about solving it.
Code:
const [topLevelHubSites, setTopLevelHubSites] = React.useState<any[]>([]);
const [associatedSites, setAssociatedSites] = React.useState<any[]>([]);

const HubSiteTrigger = (element: ISPOList) => {
    return (
      <>
        <table className={styles.hubsites}>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {element.Hub.substring(element.Hub.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  };

 const getAssociatedSitesForCollapsible = (hubSite: any) => {
    const filterTheAssociatedSites = unfilteredSites.filter((hub) => {
      return hubSite === hub.Hub
    });
      setAssociatedSites(filterTheAssociatedSites);
  };

return (
{topLevelHubSites.map((element, i) => (
        <Collapsible
          trigger={HubSiteTrigger(element)}
          key={i}
          // accordionPosition={} //could be useful
          onOpening={() => getAssociatedSitesForCollapsible(element.Hub)} >
          {associatedSites.length > 0 ? associatedSites.map((assSite: any) => {
            return (
              <table className={styles.associatedSites}>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {assSite.SiteUrl.substring(assSite.SiteUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>)
          }) : null}
        </Collapsible>
      ))}
);


As a "cop-out"/workaround I am using the open property from collapsible with a state that stores the index (i), then evaluate to see if that state is different to it's previous, if it is, then it returns true/false and closes the previous table row:
open={expandedHubSite === i}

I'd prefer to not use the workaround, so if anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate them.

Each top level site could be its own component with its own state variable for associated sites.  Either that, or you’d need an array of associated sites for all top level sites, which imo is more work and more confusing.
